# bat script 'for /F' loop filtered results

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file

I need a .bat for /f loop that will reclusively list only specified filenames from all folders (+any sub-folders) - eg 20220103_1603-Picture 1.jpg, 20100523_0900-Picture_outdoors.png, 20110901-Image of tree.gif, etc..

I have the following, but I'd like to use a regexp in the loop

```
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
FOR /R %%F IN ("20??????*-*.*") DO (
<actions>
)
```

If anyone can suggest how to use regexp's to accomplish this, or an alternative way to achieve the same result.

I've tried this, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
FOR /R %%F IN ("::[0-9]{8}[\_|\-].*\..*") DO (
<actions>
)
```

Comment: If you don't mind using powershell, powershell can do regex matches.

Comment: I'm wondering if there is a different approach to this instead of filtering results in the FOR command? eg still do FOR /R all reclusively for all files, etc.  then do a filter check within the FOR loop for the condition...it may slow the bat file tho :(

Comment: Its technically possible to make Powershell output its results to a textfile, and then use a for loop in batch against that textfile, but my experience with that is too limited, given that Powershell can do so much more, I don't see reason to use batch much anymore these days.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind using Powershell, you can use the following to perform a regex filter on a directory query.

```
Get-ChildItem -recurse | Where-Object -property "Name" -Match "::[0-9]{8}[\_|\-].*\..*" {
    write-host $_.name
    #do more stuff...
}
```

The above can also be written using aliases to give it a more CMD like appearance:

```
dir -recurse | where "Name" -match "::[0-9]{8}[\_|\-].*\..*" {
    $_.name
    #more stuff
}
```

Per request, a way to use powershell from a batch file:
It is also possible to write it such that it can be used in a batchfile, but in that case, you are more limited. Keep in mind that all commands for the loop will have to be in powershell anyway, so writing this in batch is limiting yourself unnecessarily.

```
powershell -command "dir|? name -match ::[0-9]{8}[\_|\-].*\..*{ $_;$command2;$command3}"
```

Alternatively, you can write your powershell in a .ps1 script and use the following command from your .cmd file:

```
powershell -file "C:\My path\My file.ps1"
```

The `| ?` is the same as `| where` and `| where-object`.

See also [Powershell: The many ways to use regex](https://powershellexplained.com/2017-07-31-Powershell-regex-regular-expression/)

Comment: Although I loves me some batch, powershell is clearly the answer here.  Perhaps you could add to your answer how he could call this powershell command from batch without leaving cmd.exe?

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas although I think mixing batch and powershell is a really bad idea because it makes things really unnecessarily complex and hard to read, I've added that section to the answer as well.

Comment: @LPChip thanks for the response. I'll see if i can switch to ps, since there's a lot of other coding I'll have to convert...

Comment: Yeah @LPChip.. in this case I guess it does.  I have used powershell one liners in batch many times.. sometimes the case is not as complicated (like using powershell to download instead of wget).  Thanks for adding it though! :)

Answer (score 0):

Use for /f and the dir command:

```
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
FOR /f "delims=" %%F IN ('dir /b "20??????*-*.*"') DO (
<actions>
)
```

Comment: `I'd like to use a regexp in the loop` .. this doesn't do that.

Comment: Don't think there is regex in batch....

Comment: There's no regex in batch, and furthermore, this is not doing it recursing either. Does need a /s in the dir for that to work, but given this is not what OP is looking for, I did not mention it until now.

Comment: Thanks, but yea - it was specifically for regex's - the code works otherwise with the 'FOR /R %%F IN ("20??????*-*.*") DO ()' command, but it gives false positives since its not able to pickup the first (8) digits without specifying them...